# Wrapping text in a <p> tag, when each letter is a separate <span> (for animation purposes) in react.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, gatsby

I was tasked to create an introductory text on a portfolio site that I'm building in `gatsby.js`, which has a separate animation on every letter - so when you hover over a single letter, it bounces and scales up, and then on leaving the cursor it bounces and scales back down.

I wrote a component that takes the text, splits the string into an array,  maps every letter in another component and wraps every character in a  tag with adequate event listeners and class names.

Here's how it looks:

IntroText.js

```
export default function IntroText({children}) {
    return (
    <div>
        <p className='intro-text'>
            {children.split('').map((e, i) => <IntroLetter key={i} char={e}/>)}
        </p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

IntroLetter.js

```
export default function IntroLetter({char}) {
  const [ hoverClass, setHoverClass ] = useState('single-letter')

  if (char === ' ') {
    return <span> </span>
  } else {
    return (
      <span
        className={hoverClass}
        onMouseOver={() => setHoverClass('single-letter hovered')}
        onMouseLeave={() => setHoverClass('single-letter unhovered')}
      >
        { char }
      </span>
    )
  }
}
```

and css:

```
.intro-text {
    width: 80%;

    .single-letter {
        display: inline-block;
        transform-origin: 50% 84%;      
    }

    .hovered {
        animation-name: stretch;
        animation-duration: 0.15s;
        animation-timing-function: linear;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards    
    }

    .unhovered {
        animation-name: stretch-back;
        animation-duration: 0.25s;
        animation-timing-function: linear;
    }
}
```

If I leave `.single-letter` as an inline element, the animation won't work, but the text renders fine, so, despite each character being wrapped in a separate `<span>`, the lines break on correct places. If I set `.single-letter` as an `inline-block` element, the animations work perfectly, but whitespaces collapse (hence the condition to check if char `=== ' '` in `SingleLetter.js`). If I leave my whitespaces as inline span elements and the rest of the characters as `inline-block` spans, whitespaces render correctly, animations work, but then my line breaks do not preserve words.

I could divide my string into a few `IntroText` components, each corresponding to a single line, but that, obviously, is not a viable solution on a responsive site. What should I do?

edit: I've made CodeSandbox example: [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/mmkmv7kpn8)

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? I'm especially interested in the CSS for the animations.

Comment: I've edited the original post adding CodeSandbox example.

Comment: Can you still use normal javascript in here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by keeping the words together in an `inline-block`. Check this sandbox for a working example: https://codesandbox.io/embed/jpw2l4j4py

```
function IntroLetter({ char }) {
  const [hoverClass, setHoverClass] = useState("single-letter");
  return (
    <span
      className={hoverClass}
      onMouseOver={() => setHoverClass("single-letter hovered")}
      onMouseLeave={() => setHoverClass("single-letter unhovered")}
    >
      {char}
    </span>
  );
}

function IntroWord({ word }) {
  return (
    <span style={{ display: "inline-block" }}>
      {word.split("").map((letter, letterIndex) => (
        <IntroLetter index={letterIndex} char={letter} />
      ))}
    </span>
  );
}

function IntroText({ children }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <p className="intro-text">
        {children.split(" ").map((word, wordIndex) => (
          <Fragment>
            <IntroWord key={wordIndex} word={word} />
            <span> </span>
          </Fragment>
        ))}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```